# Generate a json by formatting the return value of a method to json

Tags: c#, json.net

I want to generate a json by formatting the return value of a method to json.

Here is the format for the json:

```
{
  "Users": [
  {
    "Id1" : user.Id1,
    "Id2" : user.Id2
  },
  {
    "Id1" : user.Id1,
    "Id2" : user.Id2
  }]
}
```

The Method that should return JToken:

```
public static JToken SaveUsers(User user)
{
     context.asp_User_Update(user.Id1, user.Id2 //omitted some arguments);
     return user.Id1 + user.Id2;
}
```

I want this method whatever ids it will return to generate a json similar to the format I was given above.

I tried this code:

```
JToken json = JObject(
                       JProperty("Users", new JArray(new JObject (new
                       JProperty("Id1", user.Id1), 
                       JProperty("Id2", user.Id2))))
                     );
```

I know I need to use a loop to dynamical generate the JProperty for the `user.Id1` and `user.Id2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `users` is a list of users, you should be able to do this:

```
    JArray array = new JArray();
    foreach (User user in users)
    {
        JObject userObj = new JObject();
        userObj.Add("Id1", user.Id1);
        userObj.Add("Id2", user.Id2);
        array.Add(userObj);
    }

    JObject result = new JObject();
    result.Add("Users", array);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/n7UDae